# Upgrading MYSQL from 5.6 to 5.7

Tags: mysql-5.7

Getting this error, when updating the read replica MYSQL version from 5.6 to 5.7.
**InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 4253ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=1113 and evicted=0, during the time.)**

Comment: I know how to upgrade MYSQL, trying to understand the above error

Comment: which upgrade method you are using 1)In-place Upgrade method or 2) Logical Upgrade method

Comment: In-place upgrade